# For a tag database is it better to store filenames per tag or tags per filename?

Tags: c#, tags, protobuf-net

I want to write a small app that manages file tags for my personal files. It's gonna be pretty straightforward but I am not sure if I should be storing filenames for each unique tag, i.e.:

```
"sharp":
file0.ext file1.ext file2.ext file3.ext

"cold":
file1.ext file2.ext

"ice":
file3.ext
```

Or if I should be storing tags for each file name i.e:

```
file0.ext:
"sharp"

file1.ext:
"sharp" "cold"

file2.ext:
"sharp" "cold"

file2.ext:
"sharp" "ice"
```

I want to use the method that will give me the best performance and/or best design. Since I never did anything like this, the method I think is right might not be optimal.

Just to give more info about the app:

1. I will search files by tag. All I need is to be able to type my tags so I can see which files match, and double click to open them, etc.
2. I will use protobuffers (Marc's version) to save and load the database.
3. Database size is not important as I will use it on my PC.
4. I don't think I will ever have more than 50K files. Most likely I will have 20K max as these are mostly personal files so it's not possible for me to create/collect more than that.

EDIT: I forgot to mention another feature. Since this will be the same app to define tags for files, when I select a file, I need it to load all tags that file have so I can show them in case I want to edit them.

Answer (score 1):

It all matters how you want to search the data...  Since you say that you want to search files by tag, then your first method will be the simplest since you will only need to read a small part of the data file.

If you really wanted to be simple, you could have a separate data file for each tag (i.e. sharp.txt, cold.txt, ice.txt) and then just have a list of filenames in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching by tag, that seems like the more appropriate index.  You may incur some performance penalty for finding all tags on a file *if* that's something you need to do.

Alternatively if you do want to support either scenario: store both, and you can query on them as needed.  This creates some data duplication and you'll need extra logic to update both data sets when a file is changed/added, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

In the case, you have a lot of tags, a lot of files and a lot of relations, I would suggest using a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). In case you don't have a lot of data, I think you should not care about it.

Anyway, I suppose that even if you do want to save the relations in plain text files, the same principles as in the [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) apply. The main goal is to avoid data repetition. In your model, a tag and a file would have a many-to-many relation. I would immitate the structure of a relational database, even if the data would be stored in plain text files. I would have a file holding the filenames, one ID per filename and another file holding the tags, one ID per tag. A third file would contain the relationships. Simple, keeping files to a minimum size.

Hope I helped!